String interpolation in Azure Data Flow for source SQL query
I have following issue with string interpolation in a data flow expression builder.
I am reading values from a File via LookUp Activity in Azure Data Pipeline, I set a variable PRCTR to the value ('P00610','P00612') from a file and then assign this variable to a Data Flow Parameter.
When I start the data pipeline, my data flow gets this value from the variable:
"prctr": "'('P00610','P00612')'" and the SQL source Query I write looks like:
"SELECT VALUE t FROM c.Metadata WHERE t IN {$prctr}"

I also tried adding single quotes to the variable:
"SELECT VALUE t FROM c.Metadata WHERE t IN '{$prctr}'"

In both of the cases my dataflow is failing with error:
Job failed due to reason: com.microsoft.dataflow.Issues: DF-DSL-002 - Parameter stream  has parsing errors. Parameter(s) with errors: prctr. Not honoring the datatype of parameter(s) could be one of the causes.

I do not mark this parameter as Expression:

How should I handle such string to process it correctly? By the way when I try to pass only 1 value for PRCTR and change the query to this:
"SELECT VALUE t FROM c.Metadata WHERE t = '{$prctr}'"

it works!
So smth with a string value where multiple items exist ('P00610','P00612') is causing an error.
Please share your ideas, thank you.

Are you sure that's string interpolation and not a parameterized query? If {$prctr} is treated as a parameter, you can't pass multiple values, no matter what. Everything will be treated as a single string value. Adding quotes won't help. There's no difference between IN 'banana' and IN '(banana). In both cases you have a single string value. IF interpolation is allowed, the string value you need to pass is ('P00610','P00612') - no outer quotes

If {$prctr} is treated as a query parameter the actual query sent to the database will be WHERE t = ? or Where t=@param1 with the actual value passed outside the query itself. Even if you use WHERE t IN (@param1) it's still a single value

As I am using parameters (assigned to data pipeline variables) as embedded expressions in the string query directly, I call it interpolation. I know that "('P00610','P00612')" is handled as a value, but I want it to be correctly added into the query so that the SQL syntax will be valid.

As I mentioned before, changing the parameter value from ('P00610','P00612') to P00610 makes the statement work when you also replace "IN" with "=". So some issue is probably has to do with single quotes I have here  ('P00610','P00612') . Is there any way to see, which value is finally appearing in the SQL query within a DataFlow expression builder, I mean how exactly the final query looks like?

It looks like I found a solution using this kind of expression: "SELECT VALUE t FROM c.Metadata WHERE t IN ({split($prctr, ',')})". I also had to adapt the value I am reading from the file, changed it from ('P00610','P00612') into P00610,P00612. So hope this would help someone in the similar case.

So after all, it's not string interpolation, it's a parameter. Instead of this workaround, consider importing the list of parameters into a separate table and joining the tables. This workaround won't work for more than a couple of values. Never mind handling numbers with thousand or decimal separators
